# Javascript add element to a dynamic div

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add some checkbox to a dynamically-created div and after append the div to a static div. but I'm getting this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null

I get this error in this line:

```
document.getElementById(newDiv).appendChild(checkbox));
```

**Code**

```
function func(staticDiv){
   var newDiv = document.createElement("DIV");
   var checkbox = createCheckbox();

   document.getElementById(newDiv).appendChild(checkbox);
   document.getElementById(staticDiv).appendChild(newDiv);
```

}

```
 function createCheckbox() {
     var checkbox = document.createElement("INPUT");
     checkbox.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
     checkbox.setAttribute("name", "checkbox");
    return checkbox;
 }
```

Comment: "document.getElementById()" is for selecting things by their id. "newDiv" is NOT an ID. It's a reference to a DOM element.

Comment: Is `staticDiv` a string with the Id of your static div, or a reference to the div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is Your full code
**Code**

```
 function func(staticDiv){
   var newDiv = document.createElement("DIV");
   var checkbox = createCheckbox();

   newDiv.appendChild(checkbox);
   document.getElementById(staticDiv).appendChild(newDiv);
 }

 function createCheckbox() {
   var checkbox = document.createElement("INPUT");
   checkbox.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
   checkbox.setAttribute("name", "checkbox");
   return checkbox;
 }
```

It's causes because you are trying to get newly created Div wit ID, but you div has'nt ID :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are passing the `newDiv` element that you just created to the `getElementById` method, which should take a string.

You probably want to just do:

```
function func(staticDiv){
    var newDiv = document.createElement("DIV");
    var checkbox = createCheckbox();

    newDiv.appendChild(checkbox);
    document.getElementById(staticDiv).appendChild(newDiv);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `newDiv` is the actual element, you can simply do this:

```
newDiv.appendChild(checkbox);
staticDiv.appendChild(newDiv);
```